# TFTP server on Linux

Tags: tftp

I'm looking for an example of an FTP server running on Linux platform.

I know that there is an application on windows tftpd32 which combines multiple servers such as TFTP DHCP and DNS.

I then asked the following question:

Is it always the case for any product offering TFTP server? In other words,is it always possible to find DNS and DHCP servers in the same TFTP server.

sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

No, TFTP servers are independent. If they come with DHCP, that's because TFTP is mostly useful for one purpose - PXE bootstraping. So if you need a server to bootstrap your VMs - try [PyPXE](https://github.com/psychomario/PyPXE). Works on Linux.